# Accessing an object variable with # and space in its name in an array

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

The `$this->groups` array prints out the following:

```
Array
(
    [# Chapters] => stdClass Object
        (
            [editable] => 
            [id] => 6
            [title] => Sigma Kappa
```

I am trying to catch the [title] variable directly, without looping through the array. 
The issue is with the name of the # Chapters object.
Is it somehow possible ?

Comment: Why does the `#` and space make any difference? You access associative array elements with `$array['key']`, and the key can be any string.

Comment: yeah right... I had a hard time trying to think clear to write the code properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since its an array you can access it directly by its key. The first level (which is the parent) is an array, so access it thru `['the_key']`, then second level, is an object, so use `->property/attribute` Consider this example:

```
echo $this->groups['# Chapters']->title;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this is the only search result you find, the following is how you do it if it IS NOT an array.

```
$objectName->{'User Name'}
```